# Does LIGO support parameterized types?

Tags: michelson, ligo

Does LIGO support parameterized types?

Consider `rcons`, which is like `cons` (`::`) but with the arguments flipped.
I'd like to be able to write something like:

```
let rcons((xs, x): T list * T): T list =
  x :: xs
```

where `T` is an arbitrary type.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not yet. This is in the works though, and you are welcome to help if you are interested :)

Comment: I'll leave it to the experts for now 